# Update root Report node in SSRS report XML to include rd node

Tags: xml, linq, reporting-services, report, rdl

I have a powershell script that we run to update an entire directories worth of RDL files, by changing their connection string from shared to embedded, and adding Hidden = True tags to each parameter.

This has worked fine until we recently ran into an older report. Part of the connection update is to set the Security type from None to Database. I found in these few instances, it did't update the SecurityType node, but instead added an entirely new instance of it, causing the report to err when opened in Report Builder.

When examining the XML, I noticed that the root  node only had the default namespace in it, it did not contain the rd reference. The SecurityTYpe node however is setup with the rd reference...when powershell hits this it can't read it in and it thinks there is no SecurityType node, so it writes a new one.
This is the offending root node...

`<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">`

And this is how the SecurityType node looks in that same report:

`<rd:SecurityType xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">None</rd:SecurityType>`

If I manually add the rd namespace to the Report node, then powershell works fine. So I am wondering how I can update that to instead be:

`<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">`

This is how the PS script (using System.Xml.Linq) is grabbing the xml and the namespaces:

```
    $ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
    $rd = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("rd");
    $p1 = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("p1");
```

We then loop through the DataSource node to get its different elements:

```
    foreach($dataSource in $dataSources)
    {
        $dataSourceName = $dataSource.FirstAttribute.Value      
        $securityType = $dataSource.Element($rd + "SecurityType")
        $securityTypeVal = $securityType.Value
...
```

It is here though that the problem occurs with setting both $securityType and $securityTypeVal...they return NULL even though they do exist.

```
        if($securityType -eq $null)
        {
            $dataSource.Add([System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new($rd + [System.Xml.Linq.XName]::get('SecurityType'),'Database'))
        }
        else
        {
            if($securityTypeVal -ne "Database")
            {
                $securityType.SetValue('Database')
                $securityTypeVal = $dataSource.Element($rd + "SecurityType").Value
            }
        }
```

Is there some way else I should be accounting for the missing rd namespace prefix in the root when trying to handle SecurityType...or is there a way I can look to see if it is there, and add it if its missing? I've been trying all sorts of cobbled up ways to add it but I am far from an expert in this language and everything I have done has resulted in various errors. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The XML is invalid.  Report issue to people who generated invalid XML.

Comment: Thing is that this is historical data that holds a report RDL/XML as binary in one of the db tables, and we can't really get it updated. We need to be able to repeatedly identify these situations and handle them as they come up. Is there a quick way to simply look at that root Report and identify if the rd namespace is there or not? I'm able to pull the default ns using ContentXML.value('namespace-uri((/*)[1])','nvarchar(max)') against a cross apply to the xml, but even on a valid xml with an rd prefix, I can't determine how to pull the prefix.

Comment: The xml parsing is failing immediately.  I think using XmlReader with XmlReaderSettings will work to detect error.  Set XmlReader Settings to handle the error.  Xml Linq will use a XmlReader.  I usually get things like this working in c# and then convert to powershell.  You cannot edit a invalid xml with the Net Libraries.  You would need to use Regex to do the editing.

Comment: My bad...I kind of glossed over my own OP in that it was dealing in PS. If I simply want to look for the rd prefix in SQL (which is done well before any of the PS scripting is run), is there a simple XQuery to pull that? As noted I've only been able to pull the default to this point. If I can just nip these in the bud when we extract the rdl details from the DB I won't even have to process them then.  I've been searching all morning for what I thought would be a simple command but everything I find is way more advanced than what I need and nothing has covered what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the only reliable way is read file and handle the exception.  If you do not get an exception it means the library captured the error and you will probably get a null object.  Then all you need to do is to check if object is null (or contains no elements).